# Laravel request validation returns "save"

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am encountering a peculiar issue. Whenever I attempt to utilize Laravel's request validation, I receive a 'save' string in my Postman response. I have tried using both `$this->validate()` and `$request->validate` from the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class, and `FormRequest`. However, when I remove the validation from my function in the controller, the method operates as expected.

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel/logista/api'], function () {
    Route::post('/seller/store', 'Logista\SellerController@store')->name('seller.store');
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Logista;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Services\logista\Seller\Store;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SellerController extends Controller
{

    public function store(LoginRequest $request, Store $service)
    {
       $validate = (object)$request->validated();

        $retorno = $service->execute($validate);

        if ($retorno) {
            return response()->json(['status' => true, 'success!'], 201);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'Error'], 300);
        }
    }
}
```

**FormRequest**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class LoginRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:50',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:20'
        ];
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, I've already tried using several ways to validate the request, and in the end, when I use it, I end up returning "save." I did some more tests, and now the requests with validation are returning 404.

Comment: The string `save` doesn't appear in your shared code in any way. You're probably experiencing this error due to something before the request reaches your controller.

Comment: Likely put a dd somewhere in middlware or something, id do a global search for the string "save" and see if you're dumping out early anywhere in your code.